maximum number of search results that can be exported
I am finding that above a certain number of rows, it is not possible to export the results of a search. 15000 seems to be OK, but with 49000 rows, the export function simply does nothing. No error message, just a progress bar that stops.
Is there a built-in limit, or does it depend on installation?

This depends on your installation and the mechanism you're using for exporting.
Export <contacts/contributions/etc.> will download more records that SearchKit's Download Spreadsheet.  However, the PHP timeout setting in your server's php.ini might need to be increased.  Another possibility is that your /tmp directory isn't large enough for the file you're creating.  That would require either increasing the space, or editing your MySQL/MariaDB configuration to generate temporary tables somewhere else.
If you're good with SQL, you can also use SQL Tasks to hand-write the SQL that generates the results you want.  It has an option to export the results to CSV and email them to you.  Hand written SQL will run much faster, and I think (but not sure) will avoid the temporary table space issue.

Thank you. I'll check the timeout possibility. I haven't explored SQL Tasks yet; it's all new to me, but I would guess that I could take the SQL of the SearchKit as a starting point.

There is an issue registered that addresses this SearchKit can't export more than a couple thousand rows.
